# add component to jpanel on runtime

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a `JPanel` and `JButton` on the `JFrame`.
on runtime add `JLabel` to `JPanel` When click `JButton`.

I use of the following code:

```
 panel.setLayout(null);

 jLabel _lbl=new jLabel();
 _lbl.setText("Label");
 panel.add(_lbl);
 panel.validate();
```

but no display any `JLabel` in `JPanel`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I see you create a `JLabel` called `_lbl`:

```
 JLabel _lbl=new JLabel();
```

but you never add it to your panel. Instead you add a new `JLabel` with no text to your panel:

```
 panel.add(new JLabel());
```

This would ofcourse construct an empty label which wont be visible.

Also try calling `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on your `JPanel` instance after adding the `JLabel` like so:

```
JLabel _lbl=new JLabel("Label");//make label and assign text in 1 line

panel.add(_lbl);//add label we made

panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

With this you may also need to call `pack()` on your frames instance so as to resize the `JFrame` to fit the new components.

Also please never use a `null`/`Absolute` layout this is very bad practice (unless doing animation) and may prove to be problematic and very hard to use.

Rather use a `LayoutManager`:

- [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

or if you only have a single component on the `JPanel` simply call `add(label);` as it will stretch to the `JPanel` size.

**UPDATE:**

Here is a small sample. Simply adds `JLabel`s to the `JPanel` each time `JButton` is pressed:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JavaApplication116 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JavaApplication116().createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        initComponents(frame);

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initComponents(final JFrame frame) {
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JButton button = new JButton("Add label");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JLabel _lbl = new JLabel("Label");//make label and assign text in 1 line

                panel.add(_lbl);//add label we made

                panel.revalidate();
                panel.repaint();

                frame.pack();//so our frame resizes to compensate for new components
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: The big thing I wanted to point out in this answer that helped me solve my problem is that in this answer, all `revalidate`, `repaint`, and `add` calls are made to the `JFrame`'s *content pane*, ***not*** *the `JFrame` itself*! Take note in your own code!