# Display multiple jPanel based on a variable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jpanel

I'm stuck on my project and I have 2 days left so I hope you guys can help me.

My JFrame "UserManager" displays the user's informations which are:

- Name,address,phone number etc
- BankAccounts

My problem comes when I have to display the BankAccount objects: since every user can have an unlimited number of bank accounts - each one stored in an Arraylist called "ownedAccounts" - I want to create small panels inside my JFrame.

Instantiating the jPanels isn't a big problem: I thought I could create a class called "BankAccount Panel" and then do something like this in my JFrame:

```
for(BankAccount b:thisUser.ownedAccounts){
    BankAccountPanel newpanel;
    }
```

Or something like that.

The fact is that I'm using the NetBeans GUI Builder and I have no idea how I can place these BankAccountPanels on my JFrame and how to dynamically resize the JFrame itself (I may need more space to show every BankAccount)
Of course each panel has to be placed under the previous one.

Comment: Why not use a `JTable` to display the information, or at least a `JList`, or `JLabel`s? For sure you don't need multiple panels.

Comment: If you have layout problems, then post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - not your whole program, just the part relating to the panels and make sure we can copy-paste it to our IDE and run it. Also, post a picture of what you want the GUI to look like, you can use a simple dawring program and paste an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new panels (or derived panels of your desire) programmaticaly and add them in existing component.

I suggest creating one parent panel with layout of your choice and adding each new panel into it with `.addcomponent()` method.

If the number of accounts is not limited, I suggest using Scroll Pane.

Comment: But once I add, for instance, 5 JPanels inside a parent panel, I still have no idea how to:

1)Place every panel one below the previous one
2)Display the parent panel in my JFrame

Every time I try to add and display a JPanel in my JFrame the program just crashes

Comment: You will have to play with it a little. Create the parent panel in design mode and [choose layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to fit your needs. Maybe the best will be _BoxLayout_. You can also read [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12660321/4809220) to similar question.